# How can I globally listen for fetch completion in modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, event-listener

In my app, I use JavaScript's `fetch` to load in content after the page load has completed. Just something fairly standard, like:

```js
fetch("/memos")
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(html => {
    this.listTarget.innerHTML = html;
});
```

*(`listTarget` is just a page element. It's a Stimulus thing.)*

However, I am also using some JS libraries that scan the DOM on page load (or Turbolinks load) to inject things like icons and datetime pickers. I need to be able to tell these libraries to scan the DOM again after `fetch` completes, since the `fetch`'d content can include icons, etc.

Is there a way to do this globally, or do I have to manually call my libraries' DOM-scanning methods after every single `fetch` in my codebase? I have quite a lot of `fetch` calls.

The solutions I've found either manually call methods after `fetch`, or have to do with [the fetch event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent), which doesn't seem to support Safari, and also seems to fire *on* `fetch`, rather than on `fetch` *completion*.

I need to support the latest Firefox, Chrome, and Safari (including mobile).

Comment: You would probably want to do this on just the fragment you're inserting into the DOM, not the whole DOM after every change, no?

Comment: In my application I fire a "new-content" event (via jQuery) on the updated element. Global event listeners can pick that up at the `<body>` level and then look for content of whatever sort they're interested in.

Comment: @meagar Scanning just the fragment would be fantastic, for sure. But if here was no option but to re-scan the entire DOM, then I'd accept that.

Comment: Your options obviously depend on what the library supports.   Personally I would create a custom fetch maybe called `renderFetch` or something like that, as doing it globally on fetch could effect more things.

Comment: As an idea - you could monkey-patch the global `fetch` function and call necessary triggers or generate custom events. But there could be a lot of downsides: like, if some of triggered tools is using the same `fetch` to load resources - you could get an infinite loop.

Comment: @IvanBurnaev  You certainly could, but I'd stick a big warning symbol on it.  We all remember the days of prototype hell don't we.

Comment: I have no performance issues in my application. There are *lots* of features that rely on detecting new content (usually by class name), and lots of dynamic updates. I hate slow pages so if I had problems I'd definitely notice them, but I don't, even on mobile devices. Modern browser DOM querying is *extremely* performant.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an utility function that perform an action every time fetch is called, something like this:

```
function myFetch(url) {
  return fetch(url).then(function(result) {
    // do something...
    return result;
   });
};
```